# Build error for app using Google Maps API

Tags: build, sencha-touch-2

I have an issue building my sencha touch 2 app for production, using this command: "sencha app build production". I see following issue:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\eiamobile\eiamobile\i>sencha app build production
[INFO] Deploying your application to C:\xampp\htdocs\eiamobile\eiamobile\i\build\production
[INFO] Copied sdk/sencha-touch.js
[INFO] Copied app.js
[ERROR] UNKNOWN, unknown error 'C:\xampp\htdocs\eiamobile\eiamobile\i\build\production\http:'
```

I see the ONLY if I use external JS (google geometry) file in app.json file:

```
  "js": [
    {
        "path": "sdk/sencha-touch.js"
    },
    {
        "path": "app.js",
        "bundle": true,  /* Indicates that all class dependencies are concatenated into this file when build */
        "update": "delta"
    },
    {
        "path": "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&v=3&libraries=geometry",
        "bundle": true,  /* Indicates that all class dependencies are concatenated into this file when build */
        "update": "delta"
    }

]
```

ANY help will be appreciated

EDIT:

Adding my index.html file

```
 <html manifest="" lang="en-US">
 <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>eia-sencha</title>
 <style type="text/css">
     /**
     * Example of an initial loading indicator.
     * It is recommended to keep this as minimal as possible to provide instant feedback
     * while other resources are still being loaded for the first time
     */
    html, body {
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #1985D0
    }

    #appLoadingIndicator {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        margin-top: -15px;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        height: 30px;
        -webkit-animation-name: appLoadingIndicator;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
        -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        -webkit-animation-direction: linear;
    }

    #appLoadingIndicator > * {
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        display: inline-block;
        height: 30px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
        margin: 0 5px;
        width: 30px;
        opacity: 0.8;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes appLoadingIndicator{
        0% {
            opacity: 0.8
        }
        50% {
            opacity: 0
        }
        100% {
            opacity: 0.8
        }
    }
 </style>
 <!-- The line below must be kept intact for Sencha Command to build your application -->
<script id="microloader" type="text/javascript" src="sdk/microloader/development.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&v=3&libraries=geometry"></script>

 </head>
 <body>
   <div id="appLoadingIndicator">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
   </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to add `"remote": true` in app.json

http://mitchellsimoens.com/2012/07/sencha-touch-2/going-remote-with-sencha-command/

Comment: I see the same issue with "remote": true

Comment: I am also having the same problem and I have tried all of the above. Is there a resolution to this issue?

Answer (score 2):

[From Sencha Touch documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.Map)

To use this component you must include an additional JavaScript file from Google:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
```

So, I guess you could try to load the API this way, which is actually how they do it in the map example that comes with the framework.

Also if google is undefined when your app starts, I guess you can load GM API asynchronously :

http://www.senchafiddle.com/#MhAME

Hope this helps

Comment: loaded this way, build was successfully, but when run my app, got following error:  Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined - index.html

Comment: Can you add your index.html to your post

Comment: interesting solution, rewrite my app.js in the way you suggested, GM loaded, my app works when I run it in debug, after that I built it for production, run the app and see:  TypeError: Object [object Window] has no method 'loadApp'

Comment: @TDeBailleul your fiddle link appears to be dead.  Could you re-upload it to fiddle.sencha.com, or correct the link?